# How to create an own Timestamp every 5 Minutes for a file

Tags: php, time, timestamp

the normally unix timestamp step is 1 second. Is there a way to get exactly every 5 minute step?

i tried it with :

```
substr(time(),0,8);
```

But this is to short (99 seconds)

```
substr(time(),0,7);
```

would be to long (about 16 Minutes)

Comment: `echo date('r', ceil(time()/5)*5);`

Answer (score 0):

Ok Thanks  splash58 the correct solution is

```
date('U', ceil(time()/300))
```